# What would happen if I deleted AdSheet.app and iAdOptOut.app (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 6s, jailbroken running iOS 10.3.3. In /Applications/, there are two apps, one named AdSheet and the other names iAdOptOut. What would happen if I deleted these with terminal? Would I no longer get adds?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted those apps, you would only not be able to get ads provided by Apple's AdSheet API. Apple doesn't support this API anymore, so it would only affect a very limited number of old(er) apps.